# Compare strings in two different arraylist (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, compare

This is a pice of my code :

```
  ArrayList<String> Alist= new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> Blist= new ArrayList<String>(); 

  Alist.add("gsm");
  Alist.add("tablet");
  Alist.add("pc");
  Alist.add("mouse");

  Blist.add("gsm");
  Blist.add("something");
  Blist.add("pc");
  Blist.add("something");
```

so i have two array list i want to compare all items and check if they are **not equal** and if they are to **print out only the items that are not equal**.

so i make something like this:

http://postimage.org/image/adxix2i13/
sorry for the image but i have somekind of bug when i post here a for looop.

and the result is :

```
not equals..:tablet
not equals..:pc
not equals..:mouse
not equals..:gsm
not equals..:tablet
not equals..:pc
not equals..:mouse
not equals..:gsm
not equals..:tablet
not equals..:pc
not equals..:mouse
not equals..:gsm
not equals..:tablet
```

i want to print only the 2 that are not equal in the example they are gsm and pc

```
not equals..:gsm
not equals..:pc
```

Comment: Well I can't see the image. And what bug can you get while posting a code? I think you should try posting it again.

Comment: I don't get why "gsm" and "pc" are the items "that are not equal".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `!=` to compare strings. Use the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method :

```
if (! Blist.get(i).equals(Alist.get(j))
```

But this wouldn't probably fix your algorithmic problem (which isn't clear at all).

If what you want is know what items are the same at the same position, you could use a simple loop :

```
int sizeOfTheShortestList = Math.min(Alist.size(), Blist.size());
for (int i=0; i<sizeOfTheShortestList; i++) {
    if (Blist.get(i).equals(Alist.get(i))) {
        System.out.println("Equals..: " + Blist.get(i));
    }
}
```

If you want to get items that are in both lists, use

```
for (int i = 0; i < Alist.size(); i++) {
    if (Blist.contains(Alist.get(i))) {
        System.out.println("Equals..: " + Alist.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) but this check only the one by one how can i make it many to many check

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RemoveAll(Collection c)` on one of the lists, if you happen to know if one list always contains them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
    ArrayList<String> Alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Blist = new ArrayList<String>();

    Alist.add("gsm");
    Alist.add("tablet");
    Alist.add("pc");
    Alist.add("mouse");

    Blist.add("gsm");
    Blist.add("something");
    Blist.add("pc");
    Blist.add("something");
    for (String a : Alist)
    {
        for (String b : Blist)
        {
            if (a.equals(b))
            {
                System.out.println("Equals " + a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is:
Equals gsm
Equals pc

Comment: Ok but if i want ot check the first item of Alist  with the last item or Blist

Comment: @user1792440 I don't seem to understand your query above. Can you explain by modifying your example?

Answer (score 0):

right now your comparing each element to all of the other ones. Do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < Alist.size(); i++) {
    if (!Alist.get(i).equals(Blist.get(i)) {
        // print what you want
    }
}
```

Thats of course assuming both lists have the same length.

Comment: Ok but we dont know that every time the item will be same on the same line how can i check many to many

Comment: Sort AList and BList before checking? But then you have a problem if the corresponding items are not aligned.

Comment: give me a minute, i'll come up with a clever new answer

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing code to manually compare list elements you might consider using [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs).

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

List listA = ...;
List listB = ...;

Collection intersection = CollectionUtils.intersection(listA, listB);
```

Comment: Check the hashCode and equals methods of the objects in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class CheckSet<T> extends HashSet<T>{

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        if (contains(e)) {
            remove(e);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.add(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Add all elements of both of your lists to a `CheckSet` intance, and at the end it will only contain the ones not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
    public static boolean compare(List<String> first, List<String> second) {
    if (first==null && second==null) return true;
    if (first!=null && second==null) return false;
    if (first==null && second!=null) return false;

    if ( first.size()!=second.size() ) return false;

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String str : first) {
        map.put(str, str);
    }
    for (String str : second) {
        if ( ! map.containsKey(str) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

```
     List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     arrayList1.add("a");
     arrayList1.add("b");
     arrayList1.add("c");
     arrayList1.add("d");

     List<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     arrayList2.add("a");
     arrayList2.add("b");
     arrayList2.add("c");
     arrayList2.add("d");

     boolean isEqual = false;
     if(arrayList1.size() == arrayList2.size()){
        List<String> arrayListTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListTemp.addAll(arrayList1);
        arrayListTemp.addAll(arrayList2);
        HashSet<Object> hashSet = new HashSet<Object>();
        hashSet.addAll(arrayListTemp);
        if(hashSet.size() == arrayList1.size() &&
            hashSet.size() == arrayList2.size()){
            isEqual = true;
        }
     }
     System.out.println(isEqual);
 }
```

Comment: PLease provide some context for your answer. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

we can compare two different size `arrayList` in `java` or `Android` as follow.

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

array1.add("1");
array1.add("2");
array1.add("3");
array1.add("4");
array1.add("5");
array1.add("6");
array1.add("7");
array1.add("8");

array2.add("1");
array2.add("2");
array2.add("3");
array2.add("4");

 for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<array2.size();j++) {
                if (array1.get(i) == array2.get(j)) {
                    //if match do the needful
                } else {
                    // if not match
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ExampleContains {
    public static boolean EligibleState(String state){
        String[] cities = new String[]{"Washington", "London", "Paris", "NewYork"};
        boolean test = Arrays.asList(cities).contains(state)?true:false;
        return test;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(EligibleState("London"));
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't compare 2 Lists.